# Ajaxify This Code

Tags: posts, wp-query, jquery, javascript, html

I have some code here which updates my post query but the problem is that it reloads the page every time which I don't want to happen. Does anyone know how I can turn this piece of code to an ajax request? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
<li id="search_all" data-owner="search_all" class="<?php echo $view_all; ?>"><a onclick="dontReload();">Search All</a></li>
<li id="dealerships" href="&dealerships" data-owner="dealerships" class="<?php echo $view_dealer; ?>"><a>Dealerships</a></li>
<li id="private_sellers" href="&private_sellers" data-owner="private_sellers" class="<?php echo $view_private; ?>"><a>Private Sellers</a></li>

            </ul>
```

And here is the JS:

```
        function privateURL() {
            var url=window.location.href,
            separator = (url.indexOf("?")===-1)?"?":"&",
            newParam=separator + "private_sellers";
            newUrl=url.replace(newParam,"");
            newUrl+=newParam;
            window.location.href = newUrl;

            if(window.location.href.indexOf("?dealerships") > -1) {
               mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 12) + '?private_sellers';
               window.location.href = mynewUrl;
            } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
               mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 1) + '?private_sellers';
               window.location.href = mynewUrl;
            } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("&dealerships") > -1) {
               mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 12) + '&private_sellers';
               window.location.href = mynewUrl;
            }
        }

        function dealerURL() {
            var url=window.location.href,
            separator = (url.indexOf("?")===-1)?"?":"&",
            newParam=separator + "dealerships";
            newUrl=url.replace(newParam,"");
            newUrl+=newParam;
            window.location.href =newUrl;

            if(window.location.href.indexOf("?private_sellers") > -1) {
               mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 16) + '?dealerships';
               window.location.href = mynewUrl;
            } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
               mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 1) + '?dealerships';
               window.location.href = mynewUrl;
            } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("&private_sellers") > -1) {
               mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 16) + '&dealerships';
               window.location.href = mynewUrl;
            }
        }

        function searchAllURL() {
            var url = window.location.href;

         if(window.location.href.indexOf("?private_sellers") > -1) {
           mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 16);
           window.location.href = mynewUrl;
        } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("&private_sellers") > -1) {
           mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 16);
           window.location.href = mynewUrl;
        } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("?dealerships") > -1) {
           mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 12);
           window.location.href = mynewUrl;
        } else if(window.location.href.indexOf("&dealerships") > -1) {
           mynewUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 12);
           window.location.href = mynewUrl;
        }

        }
```

Here is my attempt at the ajax:

The jQuery:

```
$('#dealerships').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert('clicked');
        var attribute = $(this).data('owner');
        $('#search_all').removeClass('active');
        $('#private_sellers').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');


        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            data: {action: 'stm_ajax_filter'},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.stm-ajax-row').addClass('stm-loading');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                location.hash = '&owner=' + attribute;
               $('.stm-isotope-sorting').html(data.html);
               $('.stm-ajax-row').removeClass('stm-loading');


            }
        });
    });
```

The php function:

```
function stm_ajax_filter() {
$get_title = false;

$stm_listing_filter = stm_get_filter($get_title);

$listing             = $stm_listing_filter['listing_query'];
$response            = array();
$response['html']    = '';
$response['pagination']    = '';
$response['owner']     = $stm_listing_filter['owner'];
$response['url']     = $stm_listing_filter['url'];
$response['binding'] = $stm_listing_filter['binding'];
$response['badges']  = $stm_listing_filter['badges'];
$response['list_view_link']  = $stm_listing_filter['list_view_link'];
$response['grid_view_link']  = $stm_listing_filter['grid_view_link'];
$response['posts_per_page_link']  = $stm_listing_filter['posts_per_page_link'];

if(!empty($stm_listing_filter['title'])) {
    $response['title'] = $stm_listing_filter['title'];
}

if(isset($stm_listing_filter['total'])) {
    $response['total'] = $stm_listing_filter['total'];
}



if(!empty($_GET['owner']) and $_GET['owner'] == 'dealerships') {

    $ids = get_users( array('role' => 'dealer' ,'fields' => 'ID') );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'listings',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'author' => implode(',', $ids)
    );

} elseif(!empty($_GET['owner']) and $_GET['owner'] == 'private_seller') {

    $ids = get_users( array('role' => 'privateseller' ,'fields' => 'ID') );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'listings',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'author' => implode(',', $ids)
    );

} else {

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'listings',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

}    


if ( $listing->have_posts() ):
    ob_start();

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list-directory-loop';
    if(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'grid') {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid-directory-loop';

    } elseif(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'map') {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-map';

    } else {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list-directory-loop';

    }


    while ( $listing->have_posts() ) {
        $listing->the_post();
        get_template_part($template);
    }
    $response['html'] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
else:
    $response['html'] .= '<div class="row">';
    $response['html'] .= '<div class="col-md-12">';
    $response['html'] .= '<h3>' . esc_html__( 'Oops, no results found, please try again...', 'motors' ) . '</h3>';
    $response['html'] .= '</div>';
    $response['html'] .= '</div>';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

$response = json_encode( $response );

echo $response;
exit;
}

   add_action( 'wp_ajax_stm_ajax_filter', 'stm_ajax_filter' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_stm_ajax_filter', 'stm_ajax_filter' );
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts? You can start with [AJAX In Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to give you an ideas of how to use AJAX in WordPress.

Comment: Yes I have made a few attempts to no luck. I'm stumped at this stage...

Comment: It might be better to [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/303743/edit) with the code you've attempted so answerees can figure out why it may have failed. As it stands now your question is too board.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I've done that now.